# Loop through dates to get all tables by day in database in R

Tags: r, sql

I need to construct a mysql query in R that must have a date in quotes.  How can I use this with the paste function and get the quotes right?  It seems that the way quotes must be used with paste that I cannot get an R opbject to be within quotes.

For example:

```
# set the beginning and ending dates for the year 2013
date <-  as.Date('2013/01/01',format = "%Y/%m/%d")
date2 <-  as.Date('2013/12/31',format = "%Y/%m/%d")

# create a sequence of every day in this year
s <- seq(date,to = date2, by='days') 

# loop through all 365 days in the year to get a query for each day
for (i in 1:365) {
query <- paste0('select ID, Name, Account, FROM Table WHERE Date = ',s[[i]]) 
}
```

This produces the following query (for one of the days):

```
 "select ID, Name, Account, FROM Table WHERE Date = 2013-01-01"
```

But mySql requires that the date be like this (with quotes around the date)

```
 "select ID, Name, Account, FROM Table WHERE Date = '2013-01-01'"
```

How can I get the paste function to put quote around the R object?

Answer (score 2):

You can use single quotes in your string if you denote the string start and stop with double quotes.

```
paste0("select ID, Name, Account, FROM Table WHERE Date = '", s[[i]], "'")
```

Should work just fine.

As an side note, for inserting things in the middle of strings, I find `sprintf()` more readable than `paste`. Also your `s` object is just a vector of Dates, so you don't *need* the double brackets (though they don't really hurt either).

```
sprintf("select ID, Name, Account, FROM Table WHERE Date = '%s'", s[i])
```